# An efficient way to loop through an object

Tags: php, object

There's a part in my page where you can add, edit or delete school details and it were'nt supposed to save entries to the database until the user hits enter, so I save all data in an object first. My object looks like this:

```
schooldetails : {
  "1": {
    "school_ctr":"schoolctr_1",
    "school":"Fiat Lux Academe",
    "course":"",
    "qualification":"High School",
    "date_grad":"06/04/2008",
    "notes":"*graduated with honors",
    "deleted":0
  },
  "2": {
    "school_ctr":"schoolctr_2",
    "school":"College of St. Benilde",
    "course":"Computer Science",
    "qualification":"Bachelor / College",
    "date_grad":"06/05/2012",
    "notes":"",
    "deleted":0
  },
  "3":{
    "school_ctr":"schoolctr_3",
    "school":"Siliman University",
    "course":"Information Technology",
    "qualification":"Post Graduate / Master",
    "date_grad":"06/06/2014",
    "notes":"",
    "deleted":0
  }
}
```

I passed it trough ajax and I was able to save info through this code:

```
if(!empty($school_details_new)){
  foreach($school_details_new as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $school_data => $data_values) {
      if($school_data == "school")
        $s_name = mysql_real_escape_string($data_values);
      if($school_data == "course")
        $s_degree = mysql_real_escape_string($data_values);
      if($school_data == "qualification")
        $s_type = mysql_real_escape_string($data_values);
      if($school_data == "date_grad")
        $s_enddate = mysql_real_escape_string($data_values);
      if($school_data == "notes")
        $s_notes = mysql_real_escape_string($data_values);                      
    }
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `SchoolDetails` (`personID`, `School`, `Type`, `End_Date`, `Degree`, `Notes`) VALUES ($id, '$s_name', '$s_type', '$s_enddate', '$s_degree', '$s_notes');";
  $res_sql = mysql_query ($sql);
  }
}
```

This is actually working fine with me, i don't have any errors or anything but i do believe there is a more efficient way to do this without having a lot of *"if"* statements. Thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be a question better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I honestly don't think you need all the if statements. You could simple set the variables and run your insert query ?

Comment: Don't use mysql_ functions, as they are deprecated. Also prepare a statement OUTSIDE of the foreach loop, and then execute it INSIDE the loop with the values.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do it like this:

```
if (!empty($school_details_new)) {
foreach ($school_details_new as $key => $value) {

    $s_name = mysql_real_escape_string($value['school']);
    $s_degree = mysql_real_escape_string($value['course']);
    $s_type = mysql_real_escape_string($value['qualification']);
    $s_enddate = mysql_real_escape_string($value['date_grad']);
    $s_notes = mysql_real_escape_string($value['notes']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `SchoolDetails` (`personID`, `School`, `Type`, `End_Date`,  `Degree`, `Notes`) VALUES ($id, '$s_name', '$s_type', '$s_enddate', '$s_degree', '$s_notes');";
    $res_sql = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

}